# How to pass data from a label to a controller

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework

signup.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign Up" >
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="password">
        </label>

        <button class="button button-block button-positive"ng-click="insert('averyto8@vt.edu')">
            Sign-Up
        </button>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
     .controller("MembersController", function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

     $scope.insert = function (email, password, firstname, lastname, gender, dateJoined) {
         var query = "INSERT INTO people (email, password, firstname, lastname, gender, dateJoined, weeklyPoints, totalPoints) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,0,0)";
         $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [email, password, firstname, lastname, gender, dateJoined, weeklyPoints, totalPoints]).then(function (res) {
             alert("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
         }, function (err) {
             alert(err);
         });
     });
```

I am trying to pass all of this member information into the controller in my app.js file. I can't seem to find how to send user generated data from my html to the controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By using the ng-model directive on your input tags. Then you would access them in your controller via the $scope variable.

Comment: I see, sorry I'm new to Ionic, is there some place you could point me to to so I can familiarize myself with the $scope variable?

Comment: If below sound like advertisement, just google "How to get started with Ionic framework" and you'll stumble upon my posts written for Pluralsight.

I actually wrote a lot of tutorials on the topic of Ionic on my blog http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog. Also, you can take a look at my 10k word guide: http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/review/ionic-framework-a-definitive-10-000-word-guide. Finally, you can get my book about Ionic for free if you like as well: https://leanpub.com/ionic-framework.

Good luck with learning!

Answer (score 0):

I've only done for `firstname`, for other fields is the same.

**signup.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign Up" >
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.firstname" placeholder="First Name">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive"ng-click="insert()">
            Sign-Up
        </button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic']).controller("MembersController", function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $scope.data = {};
    var firstname;
    $scope.insert = function () {
        firstname = $scope.data.firstname;
        var query = "INSERT INTO people (email, password, firstname, lastname, gender, dateJoined, weeklyPoints, totalPoints) VALUES (?,?,firstname,?,?,?,0,0)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [email, password, firstname, lastname, gender, dateJoined, weeklyPoints, totalPoints]).then(function (res) {
            alert("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
        }, function (err) {
            alert(err);
        });
    };
});
```